# How to add new region in HBase?

Tags: hbase, region

My question is as the following:
I create a table with some presplit regions. As the insertion of the data, I want to add some new regions, So How can I split a specified region into two regions? Or whether can I　add new regions to the existing table?

Anyone familiar with this problem, pls help me!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can split a specific region using the split command in the shell, here's the help:

> Split table or pass a region row to split individual region

You can also do it from the web UI on that table's page (look at the bottom).

Finally, "adding a new region" is kind of incompatible with HBase's model of distribution. Regions are usually created with data, adding more data means you'll eventually get more regions. The RegionSplitter referenced by Amon and the split command are more like hacky tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegionSplitter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/RegionSplitter.html) .
Note that it is recommended to keep regions per region server in the tens (20-30 regions etc)